# How do I get the value of 'order' in sql for a given scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I get the value of an 'order' sql for a given scope?

Just like User.search('blah').where_values but for order.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.2.13 you can do this with order_values or order_clauses.

```
User.search('blah').order_values

User.search('blah').order_clauses
```